# Reputation Card Top % overall label Margin Top missing - Activity Tab, Profile Section

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, activity-tab

As shown in the image below **"top 0.41% overall"** text is sticking on reputation tile.

I think there should be margin top added to the label.

[image: Margin Top Issue]

Client Details :

Browser : **Google Chrome**

Version : **77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

OS : **Windows 10**

Zoom size : **100% (Default)**

Comment: Cross-site post on MSE: [Strange padding around reputation on Meta profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316777/289905).